# Is there a way to link workbook data without getting REF errors when a row is deleted?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

I currently have two workbooks, workbook 1 and workbook 2.

Workbook 1 - Sheet 1 is directly linking data to Workbook 2 - sheet 1.

I am linking by inputting the below formula into workbook 2.

```
='[Workbook1.xlsm]Sheet1'!C3
```

This links fine however whenever a row is deleted in workbook 1 - sheet 1, this then produces a REF! error on the corresponding row in workbook 2.

I have read one of the best ways to combat this, is to use INDIRECT to text reference the cell, the only catch is, in order for INDIRECT to work, both workbooks would have to be open, otherwise it could not reference the data.

Is there anyway to fix this issue?  I want workbook 2 to display the same data in workbook 1 via link, but can't afford a REF! error whenever a row is deleted and I also can't have workbook 1 open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this through further research.  I used the INDEX function which will still operate even if a workbook is closed.

Original Code:

```
='[Workbook1.xlsm]Sheet1'!C3
```

Changed to:

```
=INDEX('[Workbook1.xlsm]Sheet1'!C3)
```